# Buy two chocolates when want MAXIMUM nonegative spend

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, optimization

This is a self-study inspired by the trivial https://leetcode.com/problems/buy-two-chocolates/. Basically the question is as follows: if you have a value of money `m` and a list of `prices`, imagine you are a hungry child who wants to spend all of their money on two chocolates. Return the two prices that leave the least amount of (nonnegative) money left over. Is there an algorithm that solves this less than $O(n^2)$?

This problem is a form of constrained optimization, maybe somewhat similar to the problem of choosing a certain amount of coins to use up an amount of money. I am not aware broadly of what solutions fit these class of problems in the discrete case, however I do roughly know some of the tools for the non-discrete situations.

Comment: What happens if you sort the chocolates by price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Sort all chocolates by price.  For all possibilities for the choice of first chocolate, use [...] to find the best second chocolate to go with it.  Keep the best pairing found.

Fill in the [...] with an appropriate algorithm, and you can beat $O(n^2)$.

To improve the running time even further, consider: as you increase the cost of the first chocolate, what effect must this have on the cost of the best second chocolate?

> In other words, How can you avoid the full cost of a binary search?

Comment: The first solution feels really elegant to me, because I haven't seen an approach like that before. Still working on figuring out the second part, but I really appreciate the help :D